# bindparam variable has zero value after procedure is executed using pdo php

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, pdo

I'm using [bindParam](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) to bind the return value of stored procedure once the statement is executed

But i'm getting zero , i've specified output variable of stored procedure as **BIGINT**

and i'm binding parameter like below

```
$sql = "{:retval = CALL sp_testProc()}";
$stmt->bindParam('retval', $proc_pass_val, PDO::PARAM_INT|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 4);
```

**bindparam** is taking Length of data type as last parameter, i'm passing 4 here, but it returns zero, don't know why

Could anybody help me on this

Thanks in Advance

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: what could be the length of data type ? suppose i'm getting return value as 900 from stored procedure, and i defined return value as BIGINT in stored procedure, irrespective of any value it gives me zero,

Comment: it is not about length at all. it is about the proper syntax for calling *inout* variable

Comment: I'll get numeric outputs from stored procedure, I specified datatype as `PDO::PARAM_INT|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT`, even i'm getting zero, don't know why

Comment: because syntax is wrong

Comment: For some reason you aren't following the example from PHP manual

Comment: Any debugging methods to debug, I used `PDOStatement::debugDumpParams` but it gives me few info about input params, not the param values

Comment: you don't need PDOStatement::debugDumpParam at all. what you need is just an example from the manual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I've done to make it work, Hope this helps someone.

**Note:** Procedure defined in MSSQL server

Here I want email into a field inorder to get that in an array, you can omit this line `select @myemail as student_email;` and you can get the value of `@myemail` into `$myemail`

**My Procedure:**

```
Alter proc [dbo].[sp_test_success](
@Id int=1,
@myemail varchar(250)=null output
)
AS
BEGIN
    select @myemail=rtrim(email) from Student where StudentId=@Id;  
    select @myemail as student_email;-- i put this to get myemail into array 
END
```

**Code:**

```
$dbh = new PDO('sqlsrv:Server=Server;Database=database', 'UID', 'Pwd');
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("{CALL sp_test_success(@Id=:Id,@myemail=:myemail)}");

$Id = 4;
$stmt->bindParam('Id', $Id, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$stmt->bindParam('myemail', $myemail, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 500); 
$stmt->execute();
$results = array();
do {
    $rows= $stmt->fetch();// default fetch type PDO::FETCH_BOTH
    $results[]= $rows;
} while ($stmt->nextRowset());

echo "<pre>"; print_r($results);

print "procedure returned $myemail\n"; exit;
```